# React Native on iOS/Catalyst - How do I remove inspect?

Tags: react-native, react-native-macos

I have an iOS app developed via `React Native` running on macOS via Catalyst. It happened that I erroneously pressed something to enable inspection.

The fact is that I cannot remove it. How do I do?

See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: It's a really great question, the `react-native-macos` isn't simulator, because the main host OS is macOS so there is no need for any virtual OS/device. It's a pure app. And in the document of `react-native-macos` I cannot find any guidance for debugging. Have you installed the `Flipper`? It's a debugging app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, run this code and the menu will be displayed on mac simulator

```
NativeModules.DevMenu.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are five situations:

- *Physical mobile phone device*: You should shake the iPhone/iPad and then a menu will be appeared. Tap on `Hide Inspector`
- *iOS Simulator*: By pressing at the same time <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> you will be able to pop up the menu and tap on the `Hide Inspector`.
- *Android Emulator*: By pressing at the same time <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> the menu will be appeared and it has got the `Hide Inspector` too.
- *Window native app*: To see the developer menu press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- *macOS native app*: To see the developer menu press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: It's the macOS release, is it considered "emulator"? I tried cmd+m but the app goes into the dock.

Comment: `Simulator`: iOS virtual machine, `Emulator`: Android virtual machine. If you do the `⌘`+`m` on a simulator, yes, it will go to the duck. @r4id4

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Tried both cmd+d and ctr+cmd+z and none did anything on the macOS app. I've also tried to delete the derived data, but still inspector is there.

Comment: @r4id4, Do you mean, that by pressing both on Simulator you can't see the menu?

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure it's a simulator as if it was on iOS. I mean, it's a macOS app that runs in my dock and gets my Apple Id when I sign-in-with-Apple. There is no "Shake device" button, nor it works any of cmd+d or ctrl+cmd+z to trigger the dev menu. @AmerllicA

Comment: @r4id4, Check the new two items. If it doesn't work ping me here, I'll give you another option.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, I really hoped so :( @AmerllicA

Comment: @r4id4, A friend on GitHub told me, right click on app and you will be able to bring the developer menu. try it. if it works give me a shout here then I'll add it to my answer

Comment: when you say right click you mean on the app icon or the app view? If I right-click on the app view nothing happens actually :( maybe because it's a catalyst app based on the iOS codebase.

Comment: This mac shortcut doesn't work for me 